# Взаимодействие BoxCollider-ов

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Нужно, чтобы BoxCollider с героем проходил сквозь таких же других героев, но сталкивался с BoxCollider врага.

Comment: Разные слои попробуй.... https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос

Comment: @ValeraKvip мне кажется можно без зазрения совести смело скопипастить в ответ это ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Создаёшь слой для врагов, называешь его Enemies
2. Устанавливаешь этот слой префабам врагов
3. Заходишь в Edit > Project Settings > Physics (или Physics2D, если проект 2D)
4. В матрице пересечений напротив Enemies x Enemies убираешь галочку

Это уберёт все коллизии между объектами со слоями Enemiems